# super slow drill down in a 2 view dashboard in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a dashboard with only two views i.e. one bar chart and one tabular view with 12 columns. My objective is to filter the tabular view when I click on a bar in the bar chart on the basis of a column service_id.

To achieve that, I am using a set of service_id column which is acting as a filter for the tabular view. Set's value changes by a action filter from the bar chart view. So, whenever I click on a bar, set's value changes accordingly and tabular view gets filtered for that value.

The problem is when I click on the bar, it's taking more than 20s to filter the tabular view. I know that column service_id is a high cardinality column with ~65M unique values but I am using a context filter which should ideally bring it to few thousand values (as per my understanding).

Are there any ways to improve this drill down? I ran performance recording for this dashboard and the query execution to filter the service_id takes the most time.

PS: I am using an extract of 69M rows.

Comment: What is your data source? a relational database? if so, have you indexed your table with the service_id field, ideally making it a clustered index? are you using an extract? if so, did you hide all unused fields before making the index? Those are just the start of the questions.